# How can I generate a url with the username?

Tags: php

I am creating a PHP web app and I have usernames. I need to create a different url for every username. 
For example,
Bob, Alex, Rose22 are usernames, then,

```
x.com/Bob
x.com/Alex
x.com/Rose22
```

Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: I am not using any frameworks.

Comment: What do you mean create a URL?  You mean just to loop through your usernames and build out a list of URLs with each username stuck on the end?  Or do you mean to redirect the user someplace?  Like if I went to `x.com/Rick`, then it would redirect me to `users.php?name=Rick` or their own folder on the server?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the username through the url to your php script using `GET` method. Something like this:

```
x.com/?user=Bob
```

Then with a little htaccess and mod rewrite you can clean up the url and remove the `user` from it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   index.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

So it will be somthing like this after that:

```
x.com/Bob
```

And you can get it like this:

```
$_GET['user']
```

Strongly recommend you to read these for more info: 
[**Using .htaccess rewrite rules**](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs) 
 [**URL Rewriting for Beginners**](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: How will this help if OP wants to automatically generate those URLs based on username?

Comment: @admdrew He is not using any framework.

Comment: Yup, I saw his comment. Not sure how that is related to what I asked.

Comment: I don't think it's about actually generating the url string but about making them meaningful, i.e. not a 404

Comment: Based on the question, i don't see how this answer is not relevant? Seems very relevant to the question to me. He wants to build URL's based on a users username - this answer is part of the building block he needs to achieve this.